# Ocaml function call, calling itself recursively

Tags: algorithm, ocaml, ml

Here is what I am trying to do, given `z` with the signature that `'a -> 'a`,

```
let z(a)=
  if(a=0) then
    0
  else
    a * a;;
```

if I were to call repeat as, `repeat(2, f, 2);;`
then the answer should be too, since `f` should be called twice with `2`, as in `f(f(2)` the answer should be `16`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be that when you are defining a recursive function you need to tell OCaml using the **rec** keyword.

Try changing the code to:

```
let f a =
  if a = 0 then
    0
  else
    a * a

let rec repeathelper n f answer accum =
  if n = accum then
    answer
  else
    repeathelper n f (f answer) (accum+1)

let repeat n f x = repeathelper n (f 0) 0 0
```

Comment: when someone says method with a signature 'a-->'a is the way I have it correct?

Comment: `z` has signature `int -> int` in your example ShahrukhKhan. It's because `*` has type `int -> int` and so `a` is inferred to be `int`.

Comment: `paren`s and `,`s are also not necessary --frowned upon-- in these code samples when passing arguments. The `,` separates elements of a tuple.

Comment: Also, saying `(a : 'a)` doesn't mean that `a` is polymorphic. As previously noted, it has been unified by `int`. The annotations just say that it should unify with the type inferred, which it does, but does not make the function polymorphic. You will need a type parameter to a function to enforce it being polymorphic like.... `let z (type t) (a:t) : t = ...` You'll notice this wont compile with the function body you've provided.